# Ajax content into masonry isotope grid issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, jquery-isotope, masonry

I'm trying to display datas into isotope masonry grid with ajax.

Ajax calls with scroll and display works, but the isotope grid doesn't...

I saw infinite scroll plugins with isotope and some examples but I didn't find if I can call ajax with theses.

So, if you could help me it would be great !

Here is my javascript :

```
var $grid = $('#grid').isotope({
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 300,
            gutter: 25
        },
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        sortAscending: false
    });
loadmore();

$(window).scroll(function () {
     IsScrollbarAtBottom();
});

//Fonction de détéction du bottom de page. Si le bas de la page est atteint au scroll, on charge plus de postes
// Detect page bottom and load data if its good
function IsScrollbarAtBottom() {
    var docElement = $(document)[0].documentElement;
    var winElement = $(window)[0];

    if ((docElement.scrollHeight - winElement.innerHeight) == winElement.pageYOffset) {
        loadmore();
    }
}
/* //// LOADMORE //// 
*
*   On charge plus de postes, et on les construits avec buildMore
*   Controllers PHP MAIN : fonction loadmore.
*   
*/
function loadmore() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        dataType: 'text',           
        success : function(res) {
            buildMore($.parseJSON(res)); 
        },
        error: function(e, s, t){
            console.log(e);
            console.log(s);
            console.log(t);
        }
    });
}
function buildMore(datas){
    for(i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
        var $post = setBlock(datas[i]);
        $('#grid').append($post).isotope('appended', $post);
    }
}

setblock function return html block with datas
```

All of this is in document.ready scope, and scripts are called at the end of body.

I can't even understand why the grid does not work, and the `.isotope('appended', $post);` does not work too I think, because I tried to put callback with console.log after $post, and it never appears...

Sometimes I can do the grid working but only for the first loadmore call at the begining, (I know this is not really the good function name but i'll change it later.) and when I scroll and display datas, they don't care about the grid.

I'm really new to isotope and masonry so its possible I did somethings wrong.

(first question here, I hope I did'nt do something bad haha).

**EDIT**

After 2 days and more of try, I can't find a solution... I tried the infinite scroll plugins linked into Isotope page, but i couldn't find how to launch the ajax request in...

I also tried to init isotope grid at each post adding in the for loop who append posts, and did `.isotope('appended', $post);` after, but it seems like the appended event never work, I tried to put callback function with console.log and it never happend...

I'm really blocked here, and I find nothing in the web to help me...

If someone have an issue or a solution to try, i'm open !

Thanks,

Kiho